# escaping single quotes the escape character vanishes during the process using sed

Tags: bash, sed

```
#/!bin/sh
# infile is "person's clothes"
infile=$1
outfile=$2
sed -z "s|'|\\\\'|g;" <$infile >temp.txt
txt=`cat temp.txt`
echo $txt
# displays person\'s clothes
sed -e "s|paste_area|$txt|" blank.html >"$outfile"
# the relevant part of $outfile is "person's clothes" expecting "person\'s clothes"
```

"please add some context to explain the code sections" please read the code it has comments included

Comment: You need to double the backslash in `$txt`. Otherwise it's an escape character, and `\'` means just `'`

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but `echo $txt` should be `echo "$txt"` -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 2):

You need to double all the backslashes in `$txt` to make them literal when used in the `sed` replacement string. Otherwise they'll be treated as the escape prefix.

```
sed -e "s|paste_area|${txt/\\/\\\\}|" blank.html >"$outfile"
```

Comment: sed "s|'|\\\\\\\\'|g;" <$infile >temp.txt # replaces with double backslashes for dealing with more than one quotation mark

Comment: buff=\`cat $1\`
buff1=$(echo $buff | sed "s|'|\\\\\\\\'|g;") # avoids writing a temporary file

Comment: you want \\' in the output file hohoho

Comment: You can answer your own question below if you like.